# How do I check if Location is turned on or off in my Kotlin Android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, location

My app contains the following code to check for permission to use the device's location services but I need some way of detecting if `Location` in the device is turned on or off and to turn it on if it is off.

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_counties)

//        selectedCounty = intent.getStringExtra("COUNTY")!!

        // Custom action bar code to return to list of counties
//        configureCustomActionBar()

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            Log.d("Debug","Permission not granted")

            // Permission is not granted
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "Location needed for navigation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            } else {

                Log.d("Debug","Request Permission")

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), REQUEST_CODE)
            }
        } else {

            // Permission has already been granted
            Log.d("Debug", "Permission already granted")

        }

    }
```

Although permission is granted I still need some way of turning `Location` on or prompting the user to manually turn it on.

Comment: @greeble31 yes that works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
            val locationManager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

            if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) == false) {

                // Alert user to switch Location on in Settings
                val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

                // Set the alert dialog title
                builder.setTitle("Turn on \"Location\"")

                // Display a message on alert dialog
                builder.setMessage("\"Location\" is currently turned off. Turn on \"Location\" to enable navigation function in GoSiteUK")

                // Set a positive button and its click listener on alert dialog
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK"){dialog, which ->

                    val intent = Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }

                // Display a negative button on alert dialog
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel"){dialog,which ->
                    val intent = Intent(this, CountriesActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)

                }

                // Finally, make the alert dialog using builder
                val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()

                // Display the alert dialog on app interface
                dialog.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( 
   Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

```
if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
    buildAlertMessageNoGps();
}

private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
       .setCancelable(false)
       .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final 
DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
               startActivity(new 
Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
           }
       })
       .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, 
@SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
           }
       });
 final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
 alert.show();
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your help.